# MongoID Inheritance / Polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongoid

In a Rails app running MongoID, I want to create a hierarchy similar to STI
in a typical Rails app, which allows for some polymorphic behavior. In this
case, I have a `User`, which is the base type, and two subclasses, `Owner`
and `Assignee`.

These apply to `Task`s, and when a task is assigned to a user, I want to
push the `User` onto the `Task`s `owners` collection. So, `User` does not
have associations, but `Owner` has a `has_many` association with `Task`.

What I'm unclear about is how to make a `User` an `Owner` because basic
`User`s can assume the role of `Owner` or of `Assignee`. So what I am trying
to do is find an arbitrary user and make him or her the owner of a task.

I hope this is sufficiently clear to illustrate what I'm doing. Here's some
code:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # and no associations
end

class Owner < User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :tasks
end

class Assignee < User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end

class Task
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :owner
  has_many   :assignees
end

# ...

user = User.create(...)
task = Task.create(...)
task.owner = Owner.find(user)  # Doesn't work; wrong kind of document
```

Any hints on how to better structure this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need all the SCI stuff? Why not just toss the associations right in `User` and then a user with a non-empty tasks list is an owner whereas one with an empty tasks list isn't.

*Ownerness* isn't really part of a user's identity, it is just something they sometimes do. Tasks come and go and can even change ownership but none of that should alter the identities of the people involved: it merely changes their current role. Similarly for assignees.

Also, once you've included `Mongoid::Document` in a base class, you shouldn't include it again in the subclasses.

I'd probably start with something something like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :owned_tasks,    :class_name => 'Task', :inverse_of => :owner
  has_many :assigned_tasks, :class_name => 'Task', :inverse_of => :assignee
end

class Task
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :owner,    :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :owned_tasks
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :assigned_tasks
  has_many   :assignees
end
```

Then you can say things like:

```
u1 = User.create
u2 = User.create
t  = u1.owned_tasks.create(:assignee => u2)

u1.owned_tasks    # One task: [ t ]
u2.assigned_tasks # One task: [ t ]

t.owner    # u1
t.assignee # u2
```

And you can reassign tasks without changing the underlying Users, you just change the associations.

Comment: Why `belongs_to :assignee` in the `Task` model? A `Task` has many `assignees` and they belong to the `Task`.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the situation? If there are many people assigned to a task then you could use a HABTM instead.

Comment: Yes, you partially misunderstood the situation, but not to the extent that the answer was wrong. The HABTM worked fine and it helped me enough to move along. I think you'll see that I was hoping to impose a more "pure" OO polymorphism on the object graph, but this solution works just fine.